# Is if (a < 101) faster than if (a <= 100) , Please tell for javascript and php seperately?

Tags: javascript, php, performance, pagespeed

Is if (a < 101) faster than if (a <= 100) , Please explain for javascript and php seperately ?
I edited some code in javascript file 
Initial Code

```
rect.top>=0&&rect.left>=0&&rect.top<=(window.innerHeight||document.documentElement.clientHeight)
```

After edit code

```
rect.top>-1&&rect.left>-1&&rect.top<=(window.innerHeight||document.documentElement.clientHeight)
```

But my seniour says it will not make it fast. So please help.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Why would it? Also, micro optimization like this is in most cases a bad idea, it makes the code harder to understand, can introduce subtle bugs (what if rect.top is -0.5?) and you can't predict the impact anyway because for instance different JavaScript engines may handle things differently...

Comment: Even if you benchmarked this and there were a difference, I believe the difference would be so subtle that you wouldn't be able to draw any real conclusions from it anyway. Use what makes most sense regarding the logic and readability and spend your time discussing something useful instead. I seriously doubt that will be the cause of any performance issues you'll ever run into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It is not faster. Within the microcode of every thinkable CPU, the two comparisons `>` and `>=` translate to the same-length instruction.  It would not depend on the programming language used.